# how to map columns of different dataframe basis datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframe

```
df1
code     start_date             tank     product
123      2019-02-23 06:30:00    1        MS
123      2019-02-23 11:35:00    2        HS
123      2019-02-24 06:45:00    1        MS
123      2019-05-12 05:39:00    1        HS

df2
code    tank_ms    product_ms  update   from_date              to_date
123     1          HS          Dealer   2019-01-01 00:00:00    2019-03-31 06:00:00
123     1          MS          Dealer   2019-03-31 06:00:01    2019-05-30 06:00:00
123     2          HS          Dealer   2019-01-01 06:00:01    2019-05-30 06:00:00
```

Now I want to join df1 with df2 for product_ms and update with datetime comparison. My desired dataframe is as follows

```
df1
code     start_date             tank     product   product_ms   update  
123      2019-02-23 06:30:00    1        MS        HS           Dealer
123      2019-02-23 11:35:00    2        HS        HS           Dealer
123      2019-02-24 06:45:00    1        MS        HS           Dealer
123      2019-05-12 05:39:00    1        HS        MS           Dealer
```

`start_date` from `df1` will get compared with `from_date` and `to_date` from `df2`

Currently I have tried doing following things,

```
 for x in range(df2.shape[0]):
     from_date = df2['from_date'][x]
     to_date = df2['to_date'][x]
     product_v = tank_data['product_ms'][x]
     tank_status_v = tank_data['update'][x]

     df1['prodcode_ms'] = [product_v if from_date <= t_time < to_date else s for t_time,s in 
          zip(df1['start_date'],df2['product_ms'])]
     df1['update'] = [tank_status_v if 
         from_date <= t_time < to_date else s for t_time,s in zip(df1['start_date'],df2['update'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with outer join, filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and lasr remove unnecessary columns:

```
df1['start_date']= pd.to_datetime(df1['start_date'])
df2['from_date']= pd.to_datetime(df2['from_date']
df2['to_date']= pd.to_datetime(df2['to_date']

df = df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'tank_ms':'tank'}), on=['code','tank'], how='outer')
df = df[(df.start_date > df.from_date) & (df.start_date < df.to_date)]
df = df.drop(['from_date','to_date'], axis=1)
print (df)
   code          start_date  tank product product_ms  update
0   123 2019-02-23 06:30:00     1      MS         HS  Dealer
2   123 2019-02-24 06:45:00     1      MS         HS  Dealer
5   123 2019-05-12 05:39:00     1      HS         MS  Dealer
6   123 2019-02-23 11:35:00     2      HS         HS  Dealer
```

Comment: I get following error `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` when I compare dates in second line.

Comment: @Neil - I think is necessary convert datetimes column to datetimes.

Comment: My df1 has 108 rows and my df2 has 11 rows. When I execute `df = df[(df.start_date > df.from_date) & (df.start_date < df.to_date)]
` it drops df1 observations to 46.

Comment: @Neil - hmm, do yuo need match by `code` and `tank` ?

Comment: Only `tank` will also do.

Comment: So if change `on=['code','tank']` to `on=['tank']` it working?

Comment: No. It does not work that way as well. Instead of merging what if we do if else comparison?

Comment: @Neil - It is possible, but slow, need iterate a lot.

Comment: I agree but, why my records are getting deleted when I join?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193639/discussion-between-jezrael-and-neil).